# Webparsing: Get fourth <p>-tag in a div

Tags: python, html, parsing

I have this html code:

```html
<!--- (...) --->
<article>
  <div class="card">
    <p class="date">08.10.2020 - 14:55</p>
    <p class="customer">
      <a class="story-customer">Customer Name</a>
    </p>
    <h1>TITLE</h1>
    <div class="story-sharing"></div>
    <p>
      <i class="story-city"><a>CITY</a></i>
    </p>
    <p>
      "IMPORTANT TEXT"
    </p>
    <!--- (...) --->
  </div>
</article>
```

I need to parse the title (h1-tag), the City and the "Important text". I parsed the h1 tag with:

```
def connection(url):
    return (requests.get(url))

def connectionSoup(url):
    return(bs(connection(url).content, 'html.parser'))

def get_title(url): 
        return(connectionSoup(url).h1.text)
```

But i don't know how to parse the fourth p-tag with BeautifulSoup.

Comment: your question need to improve !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = '''
<!--- (...) --->
<article>
  <div class="card">
    <p class="date">08.10.2020 - 14:55</p>
    <p class="customer">
      <a class="story-customer">Customer Name</a>
    </p>
    <h1>TITLE</h1>
    <div class="story-sharing"></div>
    <p>
      <i class="story-city"><a>CITY</a></i>
    </p>
    <p>
      "IMPORTANT TEXT"
    </p>
    <!--- (...) --->
  </div>
</article>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')

# h1 tag:
print(soup.h1.text)

# CITY:
print(soup.find(class_="story-city").text)

# IMPORTANT TEXT: (this is <p> tag that follows after the CITY):
print(soup.find(class_="story-city").find_next('p').text.strip())
```

Prints:

```
TITLE
CITY
"IMPORTANT TEXT"
```